# Why won't IE and FF return the correct attribute or type for input type date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, input

Before you answer "they don't support input type date", please read the question ;)

I have this (simplified):

```
<input type="date" />
```

and with JS and/or jQuery I want to be able to do something with it, so I look for something like:

```
var input = el.querySelector("input")[0]; // returns the input
var inputType = input.type; // returns "date" in Chrome, "text" in IE, FF
```

So I tried to be smarter than that and did this:

```
var inputType = $("input")[0].attr("type");
```

but it still returns "text"..

Any ideas/hacks that can force it to return date? I would prefer not to use class/id selectors as it's for a generic system, where I don't necessarily control those.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how `$("input")[0].attr("type");` returns `text` - it should return an error as you're trying to call a jQuery method on a native element.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=date will be good one to use visit once. or simply update to latest browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little confusion here with attributes and properties.

First of all both Firefox an IE don't support `input` with `type="date"` (at the time of writing, IE11, Firefox 34). Check support [table](http://caniuse.com/#search=date). By default browser will treat unknown input type as if it was `text`. The property of the DOM element object in this case will also be `text`. this is what you are observing in this code:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var inputType = input.type; // will give `text` in Firefox and IE
```

However attribute value will still be `date` even if browser has no support for this input type:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var inputType = input.getAttribute("type"); // will give `date` everywhere
```

Comment: I don't know why I kept getting text using the second example, but it works now using this code. Thanx. (and there was no confusion — I know the diff between the attr and the prop, which is why I thought of the solution)

Answer (score 1):

Both IE and FF (and Chrome) returns `date`:

```
var inputType = $("input").attr("type");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6mnqfhe4/

Comment: It returns `date` because this is attribute. Try `$("input").prop("type")` and you will see `text`. Check my answer about difference between attributes and properties. http://jsfiddle.net/6mnqfhe4/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputType = $("input")[0].attr("type");
```

This code will not work because `$('input')[0]` returns the DOM element (not wrapped in jQuery), if you want to retrieve the jQuery element for your first input try :

```
var inputType = $("input").eq(0).attr("type");
// or
var inputType = $("input:first").attr("type");
```

Answer (score 0):

@dsfq is correct, neither FF or IE support Date fields and defaults them to behave like text fields. However, @Kristoffer is also correct in that they're still reported as "date" fields by the browser (all the way back to IE7 with JQuery 1.6.2).

```
var inputType = $("input").attr("type");
```

this code returns the type of the **first** input field in your HTML, which I assume is of `type="text"`, as this is the only way that JQuery could've returned "text", give the input your interested in an ID and use that as the selector like so:

```
var inputType = $("#inputId").attr("type");
```

or limit the selection to only pick out date inputs:

```
var inputType = $("input[type=date]").attr("type");
```

Comment: There is not magic here: `$("input").attr("type")` returns `date` because this is attribute. Try `$("input").prop("type");` and it will give you `text`, because this is property.